# Code generation for ClientBase<TChannel> and ChannelFactory<TChannel>?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, inheritance, interface

I am studying the usage pattern employed in [ClientBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and there is one point I cannot get my head around.

In most examples, we have this usage

```
public class MyClient : ClientBase<IMySvcContract>, IMySvcContract {

    // IMySvcContract Interface method
    public string MyOperation(int param)
    {
        return this.Channel.MyOperation(param);
    }
}
```

This is an example of a client calling the service method via the channel. However, when I look closely, `ClientBase` does not have any implementation of `MyOperation()`, it merely knows about the public interfaces defined in `IMySvcContract`.

Therefore, when `this.Channel.MyOperation()` is called, which block of code is it actually running? **Did it generate code to implement TChannel at runtime? If so, how else can this pattern be achieved?"**

Edit: In the simplest case, there are only 2 classes which has implementation of `ISvcContract`, the `Client` and the `Server`. It does not make sense for the pattern to create either of the object and type casting to the interface type, which is the only possible way to get actual code that I know of.

Edit 2: After further research, I now learn that it is possible to generate a class that implements the `TChannel` interface at runtime. Runtime code generation to this extent is new to me. [Reference](http://philsversion.com/2009/08/12/dynamically-generating-an-interface-implementation-at-runtime/). As a result, question changed slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientBase` takes in your service contract as a type parameter and it exposes an instance of this type via the  `Channel` property.

The channel is essentially a proxy for the communication layer the service.

The actual generation of this proxy object happens in the depths of the CLR (rather than the .NET Framework class library). I'm not sure exactly how the CLR generates the proxy but it's pretty low-level stuff.

**Update:**

I traced the code through the channel factories to the `RealProxy` class, the `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices` class (mscorlib) and the extern `CreateTransparentProxy` method that actually does the work.

I learned a bit discovering that and I share that knowledge in the sense that "the block of code" does not exist in the .NET Framework, which is what I meant by low-level.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The question is which block of code is called, and your answer is: I don't know. The other explanation in your class does not clarify the question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: disagree, this IS a good answer, +1 from me. The `Channel` is of type `TChannel`, the type provided to the generic `ClientBase<TChannel>`. The implementation is built using reflection and dynamic code generation (it's not actually "low-level" but this sounds like a good aproximation of what happens somewhere automatically).

Comment: @WiktorZychla: that's why I hesitated (and in the end did not) downvote. There is some good explanation, but in the end the question doesn't get answered (your comment is already more specific). If OP wants to see the actual code this answer does not provide the entire answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: from what I always understood, you can't really see the actual code as it is automatically generated in run-time. The `ChannelFactory` does this and you can't "step-into" as there is nothing available at the compile-time.

Comment: Actually, there was 2 parts to my question: (1) to see the code if there is any; and (2) whether it was a code generation trick. After further research, I now learn that it is possible to generate a class that implements the TChannel interface at runtime. Runtime code generation to this extent is new to me. Reference: http://philsversion.com/2009/08/12/dynamically-generating-an-interface-implementation-at-runtime/

Comment: However, it would still be important to know whether code generation was indeed used in `ClientBase.CreateChannel()`

Comment: To all, I traced the code through the channel factories to the RealProxy class, the System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices class (mscorlib) and the extern CreateTransparentProxy method that actually does the work. I learned a bit discovering that and I share that knowledge in the sense that "the block of code" does not exist in the .NET Framework, which is what I meant by low-level. I realise it does not answer question very well, but I like to share what I do discover. Maybe it would have been better served in a comment or I could edit the answer and describe the whole call chain.

Comment: @AndrewMcLachlan: you can update your answer instead of adding this content as a comment. I think your answer is an excellent answer now, you have put work in it and came up with the best possible answer. +1 from me!